# C++ Finding a string's nth character

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to do my assignment for CS, but I can not find how to get a string's first character.

Example input : 5ABCD1AB1AD

Desired output: 5

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string word;
    word = argv[1];
    cout << "Word: " << word << "\n";
    int length = word[0];
    cout << "Word's length : " << length << "\n";
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
            cout << argv[i][j] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `int length = word[0];` does?

Comment: @AlexanderZhang it is part of my assignment. The first character in string has to be the the word's length. For example if the input is 5ABCD, this inputs length is 5. I am trying to get the first char of the string and save it to the length variable

Comment: So, the first character is `word[1]`

Comment: Your description and your "Desired output: 5" don't match...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word[0]` is a character. There is a difference between the character `'5'` and the number `5`. If you assign a character to an int you will get the encoding value for that character.

To convert a character to its numeric value you can subtract `'0'`, since the encoding values for the digits are consecutive.

```
int length = word[0] - '0';
```

Comment: It’s important to note that this will work for a single digit, that is, for length values up to 9.

Comment: but for example if i want to check for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (word[i] is a number)
}

how can i do that ??

Comment: @YasinOsman If you want to check if a character is a digit you can use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).